# does 'KEY' in SHOW CREATE TABLE mean a column is indexed?

Tags: sql, select, mysql, indexing

I am dealing with a db I did not create. I will be issuing a number of long-running queries involving three integer columns of a large table: id (a primary key), x and y. (I won't be writing/updating records; just issuing queries.)

SHOW CREATE TABLE shows that:

```
`primary_key` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`x` int(11) default NULL,
`y` int(11) default NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
KEY `my_x` (`x`),
KEY `mh_y` (`y`)
```

For my purposes, should I create indices on id, x and y? Or do the UNIQUE KEY and KEY lines mean that indices are already present?

thanks!

~l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a primary key on `primary_key` - as it is `UNIQUE` is not the same as `PRIMARY`. The other two columns are already indexed - `KEY` is the same as `INDEX` in this case.

If you always search by both `x` and `y`, having a single key on both of them might improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

already present.
Use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to see what a query will do (perf wise).